# Handling 2000+ more requests on mysql?

Tags: mysql, load-balancing

Is there any tools or proper way to handle more than 2000 requests (Mostly write request) per second to mysql database? Without reaching queuelimit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to handle massive amounts of requests to a MySQL (or any other relational/RDB) database. Starting out with growing traffic you can employ replication which allows for additional machines to send read-only (no INSERTs, UPDATEs, DELETEs, etc.) from one machine and to only write to a single "master" machine (the read replicas copy the written data from the master or write-allowed instance but may be slightly behind the latest data written for a short period of time). Oracle (owner of the MySQL project) has a good article about it (and scaling PHP) here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/white-php-part1-355135.html

Once your app begins taking on requests on a truly massive scale (like Facebook, Google, etc. level) you will want to consider other strategies such as clustering, utilizing NoSQL (for certain functions such as search, analytics, logging, monitoring, etc.), splitting tables and databases based on geographic regions (if it makes sense). There is a starter white paper here: https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-scaling-web-databases-with-mysql-cluster/

You can also conduct generic searches for "scaling MySQL" which deliver even more results.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB 10+ comes with Galera Cluster that allows you to have multiple MASTER servers and you can load balance either by IP or through a device.

Also, the number or requests/second are dependent on how fast a write is completed. If you have a simple atomic raw write, you can turn off INDEXES on the receiving table, so it's as fast as your server can handle. That raw table can by MyISAM and not InnoDB. That's usually up to 10x faster in writes. Have another process read the raw data in bulk into another table with proper indexes. We've had success with up to 10K transactions/second this way